# Where do I configure if a new fragment replaces prior one or is added to the stack?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, fragment

I created a new Android Studio Project and am using the "Navigation Drawer Activity" example. When I navigate to the existing menu items the drawer is accessed via the hamburger menu again. But If I add another menu item the hamburger becomes a back arrow. I have been adding menus to mobile_navigation.xml and activity_main_drawer.xml. My new entries look identical to the existing entries in the text version of these files and in the app as well, but I guess something in another file is controlling whether the fragment is added on top or replacing the existing fragment?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue. In the MainActivity in the onCreate method, there is the below line.

```
mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_home)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
```

Each navigation menu should be listed on the same line as R.id.nav_gallery and R.id.nav_home.